# Task upstream of branch gets skipped for no reason -- Airflow 2.0 Dynamically Generated Tasks

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-2.x

### Background:

I have a DAG responsible for extracting JSON datasets from a daily data dump folder and loading it into a Redshift Database; the DAG diagram looks like this:

[image: DAG diagram]

It uses the dynamic task mapping from the Airflow 2.0 Taskflow API to dynamically generate task instances for each file in the data dump folder and load it into a pre-staging table before it all gets inserted into the final destination table.

### Problem:

From the image above, you can see that the `update_prestaging_table_columns` task and all downstream tasks get skipped right when the DAG begins running. This happens during every scheduled run, and I have to manually clear out all the tasks every time to get them all to successfully run.

At the moment, to get this DAG to work, I moved `create_destination_raw_table` downstream of `sense_daily_files` and made the whole thing a linear DAG. However, I want to know why the tasks are getting skipped for no reason with the above arrangement.

Also, looking at how the DAG runs in real-time, I noticed that `create_destination_raw_table` completes significantly quicker than the whole chain leading up to `update_prestaging_table_columns`. Perhaps things are getting skipped due to the disparity in the duration of both branches?

### Troubleshooting Attempts:

1. Looking at the task instance details for `update_prestaging_table_columns`, I don't see any reasoning for why the task was skipped:

[image]

2. I've ensured that `depends_on_past=False` and `wait_for_downstream=False`
3. I tried setting the trigger rules for `update_prestaging_table_columns` and `insert_into_raw_table` to `"none_failed"`, but that didn't work
4. When I remake this DAG using only EmptyOperators (a.k.a DummyOperator), the DAG seems to run fine. This makes me think that perhaps dynamically generated tasks may be causing an issue here.

```py
# =============================================================================
#  Imports
# =============================================================================
# System libs
from datetime import datetime

# Airflow
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator

# =============================================================================
#  DAG Dependency Orchestration
# =============================================================================
with DAG(
    dag_id="Empty_Operator_DAG",
    description="Load JSON datasets from an S3 folder into a Redshift Database",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 12, 10),
    catchup=True,
    max_active_runs=1,
) as dag:

    s3_key_sensor = EmptyOperator(
        task_id="sense_daily_files",
    )

    get_s3_keys = EmptyOperator(
        task_id="get_s3_keys"
    )

    create_prestaging_redshift_table = EmptyOperator(
        task_id="create_prestaging_redshift_table"
    )

    load_s3_into_prestaging_table = EmptyOperator(
        task_id="load_s3_into_prestaging_table"
    )

    update_prestaging_table_columns = EmptyOperator(
        task_id="update_prestaging_table_columns"
    )

    create_destination_raw_table = EmptyOperator(
        task_id="create_destination_raw_table"
    )
    insert_into_raw_table = EmptyOperator(
        task_id="insert_into_raw_table"
    )
    drop_prestaging_tables = EmptyOperator(
        task_id="drop_prestaging_tables"
    )



    (s3_key_sensor >> get_s3_keys >> create_prestaging_redshift_table >> load_s3_into_prestaging_table >> update_prestaging_table_columns >> insert_into_raw_table >> drop_prestaging_tables)
    create_destination_raw_table >> insert_into_raw_table
```

### Code:

Here is the minimum reproducible code on Airflow `2.4.2`:

```py
# =============================================================================
#  Imports
# =============================================================================
# System libs
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Any, Dict

# Airflow
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

# =============================================================================
#  Constants
# =============================================================================
DESTINATION_SCHEMA = "dest_schema"
DESTINATION_TABLE = "dest_table"


# =============================================================================
#  Decorated Tasks
# =============================================================================
@task
def create_prestaging_redshift_table(s3_uri: str, dest_schema: str, **kwargs: Any) -> Dict[str, str]:
    """Create a pre-staging table in the schema, dest_schema, with a table name
    generated from the given s3 uri. Returns kwargs to be expanded in downstream tasks.
    """
    table_to_create = f"prestaging_{s3_uri.split('/')[-1]}"

    data = {
        "s3_uri": s3_uri,
        "table_name": f"{dest_schema}.{table_to_create}",
    }

    return data


@task
def load_s3_into_prestaging_table(s3_uri: str, table_name: str, **kwargs: Any) -> Dict[str, str]:
    """Load JSON dataset found at the provided s3 uri into the specified table
    via the COPY command without shredding columns. Returns kwargs to be expanded
    in downstream tasks.
    """
    data = {
        "s3_uri": s3_uri,
        "table_name": table_name,
    }

    return data


@task
def update_prestaging_table_columns(s3_uri: str, table_name: str, **kwargs: Any) -> Dict[str, str]:
    """Update metadata columns (i.e. data_source, created_at) for the given table.
    Returns kwargs to be expanded in downstream tasks.
    """
    data = {
        "source_table": table_name,
    }

    return data


@task
def create_destination_raw_table(schema: str, table_name: str, **kwargs: Any) -> str:
    """Create the raw table, if it does not exist, in the provided schema and table name.
    Returns kwargs to be expanded in downstream tasks.
    """
    return f"{schema}.{table_name}"


@task(retries=10, retry_delay=60)
def insert_into_raw_table(source_table: str, dest_table: str, **kwargs: Any) -> Dict[str, str]:
    """Insert source (pre-staging) table into the destination (raw) table. This task guarantees
    idempotency by deleting previously inserted records from the source table.
    """
    return {"table": source_table}

@task
def drop_prestaging_tables(table: str) -> None:
    pass

# =============================================================================
#  DAG Dependency Orchestration
# =============================================================================
with DAG(
    dag_id="random_skipping_DAG",
    description="Load JSON datasets from an S3 folder into a Redshift Database",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 12, 19),
    catchup=True,
    max_active_runs=1,
) as dag:

    s3_key_sensor = EmptyOperator(
        task_id="sense_daily_files",
    )

    get_s3_keys = PythonOperator(
        task_id="get_s3_keys",
        python_callable=lambda: ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
    )

    s3_key_sensor >> get_s3_keys

    prestaging_tables = create_prestaging_redshift_table.partial(dest_schema=DESTINATION_SCHEMA).expand(s3_uri=get_s3_keys.output)
    prestaging_tables = load_s3_into_prestaging_table.expand_kwargs(prestaging_tables)
    prestaging_tables = update_prestaging_table_columns.expand_kwargs(prestaging_tables)

    destination_raw_table = create_destination_raw_table(
        schema=DESTINATION_SCHEMA,
        table_name=DESTINATION_TABLE,
    )

    prestaging_tables = insert_into_raw_table.partial(dest_table=destination_raw_table).expand_kwargs(prestaging_tables)

    drop_prestaging_tables.expand_kwargs(prestaging_tables)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble with consecutive dynamic tasks.

this thread can help you solve the bug

https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/28973

yes you are right, using an empty operator to break the sequence of dynamic tasks solves the bug

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34140380)

Comment: Please include the essential information of the linked source.